# Security of a Yahoo! ID beyond passwords?

Tags: security, yahoo-account

Is there a way to secure my Yahoo! ID information beyond passwords?

What I mean is for example, Google has implemented a 2-way verification wherein, after a Google account logs in to a new computer besides the one I typically use, it requests for a validation code that it can use to verify my authenticity and thus, would send a verification code to my 'phone via text.

For Facebook, I set it so that if a new computer uses my Facebook account, the user will be asked to enter a computer name or identity and I will be notified that `x` computer signed in to my account thus giving me enough time to go online and possibly gain control of my Facebook account.

As for Yahoo!, what options do I have?

Answer (score 2):

As of March 2011, I don't think Yahoo implement the functionality you are asking for.

If you are concerned about security then the only thing I can recommend is:

- Reduce the amount of time Yahoo keeps you signed in for to a day.
- Implement the [Sign-In Seal](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/edit/privacy/edit-39.html;_ylt=AsSW7RTyrbVl9DTajEafGpSYkiN4)
- Set your [default Location](http://location.yahoo.com/locationmgt/?locale=en-US) and periodically check it to see if anyone has logged in to your account elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo offers [Add two-step verification for extra security](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN5013.html?redirect=true):

> Two-step verification is another layer of security that uses your
> password plus a code to verify your identity when you sign in to your
> account on a new, unrecognized device for the first time or after
> clearing the cache in your browser. We'll send your cell phone a code
> by text or phone call that only you'll have access to.
>
> ## Turn two-step verification on or off
>
> If you lose your cell phone, you'll need to sign in on a recognized
> device that you've used in the past to sign in to your Yahoo account.
>
> 1. Sign in and go to your Account security page.
> 2. Next to Two-step verification, click the toggle button to enable
>    click the on-Off icon in the two-step verification process.
> 3. Enter your mobile number.
> 4. Click Send SMS to receive a text message with a code or Call me to
>    receive a phone call.
> 5. Enter the verification code | click Verify.
> 6. The next window refers to the use of apps like iOS Mail or Outlook.
>    Click Create app password to reconnect your apps. See the section below for more info.
>
> **Want to turn it off?** Simply click the **toggle button** Use the on-off
> button under **Two-step verification** to disable.
>
> ## Using two-step verification with apps
>
> Some apps (like iOS Mail, Android Mail, Outlook, and Yahoo messenger
> for PC) require a specific password to connect that app with Yahoo. If
> you enable two-step verification, you'll need to create a third-party
> app password to use in apps like these.